# How to search in HBase using LIKE in ROWID?

Tags: hbase

ROWIDs of my Hbase table are construncted in such a way that its first substring is a fixed string say ABC and rest is variable. For example my rowids look like:

```
ABC_12345
ABC_89778
ABC_64994
...
..
```

How can I write an HBASE query to SCAN my table using some Row Filter implementation in such a way that if I supply 'ABC', I get all the rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
U

Answer (score 4):

You can use both, a `Scan` with a `RegexStringComparator` Filter. Something like this :

```
String regEx = "^ABC";
Filter regExFilter = new RowFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, 
                        new RegexStringComparator(regEx));
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(regExFilter);
```

Comment: How can you do it in HBase shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SubstringComparator also.
From the docs:
This comparator is for use with SingleColumnValueFilter, for filtering based on the value of a given column. Use it to test if a given substring appears in a cell value in the column. The comparison is case insensitive.
Only EQUAL or NOT_EQUAL tests are valid with this comparator.

For example:
    `SingleColumnValueFilter scvf =`
    `new SingleColumnValueFilter("col", CompareOp.EQUAL,`
    `new SubstringComparator("substr"));`

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SubstringComparator.html